# Erlang Badarith Error

Tags: erlang

The below Erlang function results in badarith error sometimes even when the values of Lat and Distance are float values
What could be the reason and what can be done to avoid it ?

```
-define(EARTH_RADIUS, 6372800).
-define(PI, ct_expand:term(math:pi())).
-define(RAD_FACTOR, ct_expand:term(?PI / 180)).
add_distance_lat(Lat, Distance) ->
    Lat + ((Distance / ?EARTH_RADIUS) / ?RAD_FACTOR).
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the complete `badarith` error? It might contain more clues. For a function like this, I would add guards: `add_distance_lat(Lat, Distance) when is_number(Lat), is_number(Distance) ->` in order to catch the error earlier.

Comment: Thanks @legoscia for the guards idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The below Erlang function results in badarith error sometimes even
>   when the values of Lat and Distance are float values

I don't know what the `ct_expand:term` does, but you can easily test that `add_distance_lat()` does not cause a `badarith` error when given two floats as arguments.  I removed `ct_expand:term` from the following code:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

-define(EARTH_RADIUS, 6372800).
-define(PI, math:pi()).
-define(RAD_FACTOR, ?PI / 180).

test(0) -> ok;
test(N) ->
    X = rand:uniform() * 1000,
    Y = rand:uniform() * 10000,
    io:format("X=~w, Y=~w~n", [X, Y]),
    ok = add_distance_lat(X, Y),
    test(N-1).


add_distance_lat(Lat, Distance) ->
    try Lat + ((Distance / ?EARTH_RADIUS) / ?RAD_FACTOR) of
        _GoodResult -> ok
    catch
        error:Error -> Error;
        _:Other -> Other
    end.
```

Here's what running the test 10 times looks like:

```
5> c(my).       
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

6> my:test(10). 
X=169.43178167665917, Y=994.0890019584891
X=106.80009354948483, Y=5318.014760525637
X=483.5152966069006, Y=849.1797017589287
X=413.42192963089917, Y=1813.3077771861872
X=695.5858531252752, Y=6659.873970151745
X=476.4974288029442, Y=3429.9745843747255
X=352.2598626576124, Y=5441.283558914134
X=189.92661305858994, Y=7267.19292963693
X=525.3094754648756, Y=6112.466577043024
X=629.8521203556536, Y=8758.910589712157
ok
```

The fact that ok was returned on the last line means that `add_distance_lat()` performed without error.  If there was an error, then you would get a badmatch here:

```
ok = add_distance_lat(X, Y),
```

because `add_distance_lat()` would not return `ok`.  Here's an example:

```
test() ->
    ok = add_distance_lat(12.34567, '10.1111').


add_distance_lat(Lat, Distance) ->
    try Lat + ((Distance / ?EARTH_RADIUS) / ?RAD_FACTOR) of
        _GoodResult -> ok
    catch
        error:Error -> Error;
        _:Other -> Other
    end.

In the shell:

11> c(my).    
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

12> my:test().
** exception error: no match of right hand side value badarith
     in function  my:test/0 (my.erl, line 15)
```

The error says that the right hand side of this line:

```
ok = add_distance_lat(12.34567, '10.1111').
```

is the atom `badarith`, which does not match the atom `ok`.

You can comment out the `io:format()` statement in the first test() example, then run the test 100,000,000 times.  If `ok` is returned, then there was no `badarith` error:

```
7> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

8> my:test(100000000).
ok
```

I'm pretty confident that `add_distance_lat()` handles floats with aplomb.

On the other hand:

```
3> my:add_distance_lat(30.45, "20.11").
badarith

4> my:add_distance_lat('1000.24', 12.123412341324).
badarith
```

As `legoscia` suggested, if you add the `is_number()` guards to your function, then you'll get a function_clause error (no matching function clause is found when evaluating a function call) if you don't provide floats or integers as arguments:

```
add_distance_lat(Lat, Distance) when is_number(Lat), is_number(Distance) ->
    Lat + ((Distance / ?EARTH_RADIUS) / ?RAD_FACTOR).
```

In the shell:

```
5> c(my).                                          
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

6> my:add_distance_lat(30.45, "20.11").
** exception error: no function clause matching my:add_distance_lat(30.45,"20.11") (my.erl, line 27)

7> my:add_distance_lat('1000.24', 12.123412341324).
** exception error: no function clause matching my:add_distance_lat('1000.24',12.123412341324) (my.erl, line 27)
```

If you don't get the `function_clause` error with your data, then look to `ct_expand:term` for the problem.